# How to automatically import Google Calendar events into an iCloud calendar?

Tags: icloud, calendar, ical, google-calendar

I have a Google Calendar from a work account, and I have my personal iCloud calendar that I share as a read-only calendar with a few people. I'd like the events from the Google Calendar to show up (and update when needed) in my existing iCloud calendar.

There are a lot of resources to subscribe to a Google Calendar from a Mac or iPhone, but I'm not looking to add another calendar to the Calendar and Fantastical apps. Google offers a private iCal (`.ics`) URL that the macOS Calendar app can fetch and represent as a distinct calendar from the one I already have in iCloud.

I'm specifically looking for a way to automatically fetch and add/remove events from Google Calendar into my existing iCloud calendar.

Is this possible? Either as a built-in feature I'm missing or as a utility app.